# How can I link a component in React NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, hyperlink

I have created a component that I call in another component with properties title and icon:

`<HeaderItem title="HOME" Icon={HomeIcon} />`

How can I do it now if I want to put a link on this? I have tried with an onClick but it's not working, I have tried also with property path='' and to='' with 0 results.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap your `HeaderItem` component with a `Link` component.

```
<Link href={YOUR URL} >
    <HeaderItem title="HOME" Icon={HomeIcon} />
</Link>
```

[More about Next.js's `Link` component](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/navigate-between-pages/link-component)

Comment: I like Link, but you can also use Router.push() if it needs to be used programmatically and not as a clickable event.

Comment: The `HeaderItem` should also be wrapped in an `<a>` element.

Comment: This does not work in NextJS but I found a link in the documentation that gives the solution: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

The part that says "If the child is a functional component" seems like it's something related with passHref but still didn't find the way to manage it on my project. I will when I have time, I hope.